# 0 value in my primary key mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Just a thought, would there be any problem if I have a 0 value of primary key in db table? Like performance issue, security, conflicts, etc.

```
+-------+---------+
|  key  |  value  |
+-------+---------+
|   0   |   a     |
|   1   |   a     |
|   2   |   ab    |
+-------+---------+
```

Comment: is there any reason you want to use zero?

Comment: If you want to talk about performance and security, your question would probably be better fit at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't cause any problems...

Comment: it has no impact on either of those.

Comment: Even if my value for `key 0 and 1` is the identical?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's an actual reason to use 0, I'd omit it so that you can do a simple truthiness test on the values.  Are you not doing an auto incrementing primary key (which would normally start at 1)?